# What does it mean when LASSO selects 0 non-zero coefficients?

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

I've encountered a few scenarios in which a LASSO model sets all coefficients to 0.  There are variables that were selected for LASSO that explain the model better than the intercept, so I'm not sure what causes this.

Are there some common pitfalls in LASSO model building that would result in no variables included/all coefficients 0?

Comment: did you apply scaling?

Comment: How high is your $\lambda$? What made you decide to give it that value? And what lets you judge "explain the model better"?